# How to prove the inequality easily?

Tags: inequality

Let $(a, b, c, d) \in \mathbb{R}^4$. Prove that
$$|\max (a, b)-\max (c, d)|+|\min (a, b)-\min (c, d) | \leq |a-c|+|b-d|$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1)$ Inequality is invariant if we swap $(a,b)\leftrightarrow(c,d)$ or $(a,c)\leftrightarrow(b,d)$, so assume $a$ is the smallest.

$2)$ Now we have $a\leq b$, if $c\leq d$ then eqaulity holds, so assume $d\leq c$.

$3)$ Now we have $a\leq b$ and $a\leq d\leq c$, so only two cases left:

$3.1)$ If $b\leq c$, then LHS $=(c-b)+(d-a)=(c-a)+(d-b)=$ RHS.

$3.2)$ If $b\geq c$, then LHS $=(b-c)+(d-a)\leq(b-c)+(d-a)+2(c-d)=(c-a)+(d-b)=$ RHS.

Answer (score 1):

The cases where $a=b$ or $c=d$ (or both) are trivial. Therefore, we might just deal with the cases where $a \neq b$ and $c \neq d$. With this in mind, notice that

$$ \text{if } \max(a,b) = a \, \text{ then } \min(a,b) = b \quad \text{(and vice-versa)}$$

and that the same works for the pair $(c,d)$. With this in mind, there are not many cases to analyze and (even better) some of these cases actually coincide. So, let's go through them:

- Suppose that $\max(a,b) = a$ and $\max(c,d) = c.$ This is the trivial case, in which we have

$$ |\max(a,b) - \max(c,d)| + |\min(a,b) - \min(c,d)| = |a-c| + |b-d|, $$

proving the inequality.

- Suppose that $\max(a,b) = b$ and $\max(c,d) = d.$ This coincides with the previous case (sum is commutative in $\Bbb R_0^+$).
- Suppose that $\max(a,b) = a$ and $\max(c,d) = d.$ Then, we can write

$$ |\max(a,b) - \max(c,d)| + |\min(a,b) - \min(c,d)| = |a-d| + |b-c|.$$

Now, you can sum and subtract $c$ to the first modulus and do the same in the second modulus with $d$ instead of $c$. After this, you apply the usual triangle inequality to obtain

$$ |a-d| + |b-c| = |(a-c)+(c-d)| + |(b-d)+(d-c)| \leqslant |a-c| + |b-d| $$

(notice that $|c-d| = |d-c|$ so these two cancel each other). This is enough to deal with this case.

- Suppose that $\max(a,b) = b$ and $\max(c,d) = c.$ This coincides with the latter case.

These are all the cases possible and hence we've shown the inequality wanted.